# Load .zip file in UIWebview swift

Tags: swift

Hi I am new to swift development. And I trying to open files saved in the data directory of application to a webview. And its working fine if the file is image,pdf or doc. But if the file is zip then I am getting a blank page. Here is the code I used for loading files in the webview

```
if let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: path){
 var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
 web.loadRequest(request)
 }
```

What is wrong here. please help me...

Comment: How do you expect to display a zip file in a webview?

Comment: I want to display it like Dropbox app displaying zip files